# Unable to find feature.xml in directory

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I just added a plugin to my Eclipse RCP project and am getting the error: Unable to find feature.xml in directory

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

You have probably installed the plugin incorrectly. The feature needs to be unpacked in order for it to work. What happens now is that Eclipse is looking for a `feature.xml` file but only finding the jar file. 
Check your `.../eclipse/features` catalaog and you will find jar'd features. Using a program and unzipping the jar file should solve the problem.

If you install using an update site the feature will be unpacked automatically.

Discussion about this fault here:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t92012.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs if you install the plugin+feature not via update site.

Answer (score 0):

check configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info to see whether your plugins has registered here.