# Executing headless eclipse in command line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin, headless

Following [this instruction](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200508/20050823-HeadlessHelloWorldInEclipse.html), I could run headless Eclipse plugin in side Eclipse IDE.

[image]

I've got some error log info, but I guess I could ignore it based on this post - [Unable to find feature.xml in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800634/unable-to-find-feature-xml-in-directory)

[image]

Following the instruction in site, I could generate the jar file. After copying the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar, I tried to execute the jar file

```
java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -application headlessHello_1.0.0.201210101430.jar
```

I tried

```
java -cp .:org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -application headlessHello_1.0.0.201210101430.jar
```

to get error message

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/Users/users/Desktop/configuration/1349897444823.log
```

with this log file

```
!SESSION Wed Oct 10 14:30:44 CDT 2012 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2012-10-10 14:30:44.843
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

### ADDED

From [this site](http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=25800), the issue was because I didn't setup `%R2_HOME%/plugins` correctly. After the setup, I still get the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of headless Eclipse needs to include many plugins, not just your plugin. A minimal product includes:

- `org.eclipse.core.runtime`
- `org.eclipse.core.variables`
- <your plugin(s) here>

**EDIT**

I generated the product, and here is the list of plugins used by my "minimal" headless Eclipse:

I output the product, and here is the list of plugins loaded:

```
org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20100505-1235.jar
org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.1.R36x_v20100824.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20100517.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.3.0.v20100520
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.6.0.v20100505.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.1.R36x_v20100803.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.3.0.v20100503.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.0.v20100503.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.2.100.v20100503.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.100.v20100503.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar
```

So, might I recommend that you create a product for this Eclipse application you are building, and try that. Looking for a FAQ I found this. http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_minimal_Eclipse_configuration%3F

Comment: I output the product, and here is the list of plugins loaded:

Comment: I could solve this issue, but I had another issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829028/config-ini-file-setup-for-headless-eclipse