# config.ini setup for headless eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, headless

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827104/executing-headless-eclipse-in-command-line), I have this error message when I tried to execute headless eclipse code.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I googled to find this as an answer to issue:
["Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/i-am-getting-a-following-error-while-launching-my-eclipse)

However, I'm not exactly sure how to put the config.ini and how to put the correct content to  remove the error message.

This is my directory structure, and I have `Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@` inside the eclipse.ini file.

[image]

How do I setup the eclipse.ini file, and where the file should be located?

The jar files are in `plugins` directory, and `runme.sh` has this script:

```
R2_HOME=.
LIBS=plugins
JARS=.:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.100.v20110404.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20110110.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20110321.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.4.1.R37x_v20110725.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.500.v20110928-1503.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.0.v20110513.jar:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.200.v20110110:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415

java -cp $JARS org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -application headlessHello2_1.0.0.201210101509.jar
```

### ADDED

Based on Paul's answer, I copied the config.ini file to the directory where the plugin is exported.

[image]
[image]

I also modified the script to make the `-application` points to the correct id.

```
R2_HOME=.
LIBS=plugins
JARS=.:\
$LIBS/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar:\
...
$LIBS/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415:\
headlessHello2_1.0.0.201210101509.jar

java -cp $JARS org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -application headlessHello2.id2
```

Running this script gives me some more files in `configuration` directory, but I still have another error message.

[image]

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator headlesshello2.Activator for bundle headlessHello2 is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Are you running a headless application that depends on org.eclipse.core.runtime?

Comment: I'll also add your script feeds a .jar into -application, but it should be the ID of the application defined in your plugin.xml

Comment: Could you elaborate? I have `id2` as id automatically generated from eclipse. And my plugin is headless application that depends on org.eclipse.core.runtime as I followed this tutorial - http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200508/20050823-HeadlessHelloWorldInEclipse.html

Comment: you have '-application headlessHello2_1.0.0.201210101509.jar' listed above.  That's not the ID of your headless application.  But that wouldn't prevent your application from starting.  You have to figure out the config.ini first.

Comment: Have you created a working headless launch config within eclipse?  That will tell you the list of plugins you need.  Have you exported your application?  That will create a config.ini for you.

Comment: @Paul : Yes, I have a working headless eclipse plugin working in IDE. Could you give me a pointer how to get the list of plugins from eclipse IDE? And for exporting, I couldn't get config.ini, but only one jar file.

Comment: There are usually other errors that go along with that (like an exception during your `bundle#start(*)` method) that makes the activator invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a product (even a plugin-based product) works much better for providing what you need to get a running RCP application.

But if you've already created a launch config for your headless app, you can find out exactly what bundles you need and potentially what an config.ini file looks like by looking in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/<launch-config.name>`.  There should be a config.ini that PDE generated to launch your headless app.

I'd still recommend creating a .product file for your application and exporting that, unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: I tried exporting .product file, but I got some errors. I opened another post for it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831648/exporting-headless-eclipse-application-causes-the-products-defining-plug-in-c.

Comment: I also updated my original post. I could remove the first error, but now I got different one. Thanks.