# Exporting headless eclipse application causes 'The product's defining plug -in could not found' error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, headless

Following the tutorial in [this post](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200508/20050823-HeadlessHelloWorldInEclipse.html), I could generate the headless eclipse plugin working in eclipse IDE.

By following [Paul's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831435/260127), I tried to creating a `.product` file and exporting it.

Beforehand, I needed to make product configuration, and I followed the instruction in this site - http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F

This is `productConfiguration.product` that was generated automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>
<product useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">
   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>
   <launcherArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>
   <plugins>
   </plugins>
</product>
```

I followed the wizard:

[image]

[image]

However, I got this error message. I tried without `Synchronize before exporting`, I got another error.

[image]
[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: It matters what you have defined in the .product file.

Comment: I just used the automatically generated .product file. I updated my post.

Comment: your product config includes no features or plugins.  You need to add your application plugins, and then add all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension to one of your plugins.

```
<extension id="foo" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product application="com.example.FoorBarApp" name="foo">
     <property name="appName" value="foo"/>
  </product>
</extension>
```

and add the ID (plugin ID + "." + extension ID) to the product configuration.

```
<product id="myplugin.foo" ...
```