# How do you create a custom project type (from my plugin) without opening Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin for Eclipse. With the help of this plugin, I am creating a new type of project, let's say `XTypeProject`. The creation of this `XTypeProject` is similar to any other type of project you create in Eclipse.

> File -> New -> YourProjectType

I just want to know whether there is any way I can create a simple `XTypeProject` in Eclipse through some external mechanism, anything, and this project created through an external mechanism has to be similar to the project I create using Eclipse. Can Maven help me in this? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Took the liberty of making the title a bit more succinct, and made small grammar and formatting improvements. Have you considered using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for this task?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter : Thanks for the edit, bro.No. I haven't tried ANT as of now, I am just looking into more options and will pick the best.

Comment: It's been a while since I've fiddled with plugin-based projects in eclipse (RCP), but iirc your plugin should have some sort of "entry point" for new projects, i.e. some method that gets kicked off when the user creates a new project via the menu. Ant should be more than capable of - and in fact the perfect tool for - initiating that same call, though of course it may take some fiddling to get the classpath, plugins, etc. set up as required. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827451/983430) may help with that.

Comment: Don't spam SO with duplicates of your question. Consider closing your previous one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906954/java-code-to-create-a-project-in-eclipse-without-opening-eclipse

Comment: I have marked that duplicate, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Ravish Ravat, I'm looking for a plugin doing exactly what you are describing above (one that creates a custom project in eclipse) would you like to provide your code? That would be great!

Comment: Sorry Ravish, just realized the below answear ist yours. I undestand. sadly thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are my findings :-**

1. I went through the advice of Amos M. Carpenter and searched for the source code of the plugin that I have written.
2. After that, I did a debug (Plugin Debug) and searched for the methods that are called when we create a project from the Eclipse menu.
3. I took a note of all those class files and their methods that are called and the information/parameters they need for further processing.
4. I initiated the same call through ANT and was able to do what I wanted.

Thank you for the support.

P.S - I can't share my Plugin details as it is written for an organisation.