# Unable to launch Eclipse RCP Application on OS X

Tags: bash, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to launch an Eclipse RCP Application using Shell Script on OS X using Eclipse Indigo plugin with Java 1.6. The version of OS is 10.11.3 
The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
app_cmd="\"$DIR/../Resources/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java\" 
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Xdock:name=GS\ Risk
-Xdock:icon=\"$DIR/../Resources/AppIcon.ico\"
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true
-jar \"$DIR/../Resources/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar\"
-data @noDefault 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-os macosx 
-ws cocoa 
-arch x86_64 
-nl en_US 
-consoleLog 
-console 
-showsplash
AppName"

runCommand() { 
    typeset cmnd="$*" 
    typeset ret_code
    echo cmnd=$cmnd 
    eval $cmnd 
    ret_code=$?
    case $ret_code in 
    0)   
        printf "[%s] exit OK." "$NAME"   
        ;; 
    23)   
        printf "[%s] requested a restart. Restarting..." "$NAME"   r
        unCommand "$cmnd"   
        ;; 
    *)
        printf "Error : [%d] when executing command: '$cmnd'" $ret_code   
        ;; 
    esac 
    printf "\n" 
    exit $ret_code 
}

runCommand "$app_cmd"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
!SESSION Thu Feb 18 21:50:11 GMT+05:30 2016 ------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-02-18 21:50:11.660
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: It's giving the same error and somehow using the system vm even if I update the plist or ini file. The application needs to use the specific jre

Comment: Try to unzip your files with another tool and check your paths, folder+file names.... Source: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/24093/

Comment: There is no zip. I am trying to create an installer

Comment: Have you read and understood [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)?

Comment: I believe this other thread will answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827104/executing-headless-eclipse-in-command-line

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is with the Java command that is run rather than with the Bash code that runs it, but the Bash code has problems that make it difficult to debug.  One problem is that a string is used to store a command, options, and arguments.  This is generally a bad idea because it makes it difficult to avoid problems with pathname expansion (globbing) and word splitting.  Another problem is the use of `eval`, which is best avoided, and rarely necessary.  This is a slightly modified version of the code that uses arrays to store the command and doesn't use 'eval':

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

app_cmd_parts=(
    "$DIR/../Resources/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java"
    -XstartOnFirstThread
    -Xdock:name='GS Risk'
    -Xdock:icon="$DIR/../Resources/AppIcon.ico"
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
    -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true
    -jar "$DIR/../Resources/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
    -data @noDefault
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    -os macosx
    -ws cocoa
    -arch x86_64
    -nl en_US
    -consoleLog
    -console
    -showsplash
    AppName
)

runCommand() {
    typeset cmd_parts=( "$@" )
    typeset ret_code
    printf 'cmd_parts=('
    printf ' %q' "${cmd_parts[@]}"
    printf ' )\n'
    "${cmd_parts[@]}"
    ret_code=$?
    case $ret_code in
    0)
        printf "[%s] exit OK." "$NAME"
        ;;
    23)
        printf "[%s] requested a restart. Restarting..." "$NAME" runCommand "${cmd_parts[*]}"
        ;;
    *)
        printf "Error : [%d] when executing command: '${cmd_parts[*]}'" $ret_code
        ;;
    esac
    printf "\n"
    exit $ret_code
}

runCommand "${app_cmd_parts[@]}"
```

This should be easier to debug.  Run it with `bash -x` to see exactly what it is doing.  Copy and paste the text between the brackets in the `cmd_parts=( ... )` output to re-run the Java command that the program ran.  Hopefully that will enable you to determine what is wrong with the command, and how to fix it.